# PHP version of pseudo after tag

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I am working on a project involving tens of thousands of files that I downloaded from the internet. The source of the pages (MO government) didn't program the pages too well.

I am pulling certain elements from the pages to be put into another page to be referenced in my website better. **Here is a working example:**

```
<div id="intsect">
    <strong>Common law in force--effect on statutes.</strong>
</div>


// PHP CODE
// Load Document
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
// Load File Values
    @$doc->loadHTMLFile("stathtml/" . $file);

// Load the <div id="intsect"></div> value
    $genAssem = $doc->getElementById("intsect");
// Appropriate value
    $genAssem = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Statute Name: </b>" . $genAssem->textContent . "<br><br>";

# VALUE (example)
    Statute Name: Common law in force--effect on statutes.
```

Here is the part that is killing me:

```
<div id="intsect">
    <strong>Common law in force--effect on statutes.</strong>
</div>

<!-- THIS PART -->
<p> 1.035.  Whenever the word "voter" is used in the laws of this state it shall mean registered voter, or legal voter.
```

The programmers didn't give it an ID or a Class. I need to extract the paragraph tag that follows `#intsect`. **Is there a PHP selector that can select the `<p></p>` tags after the `#intsect` one?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xpath` to target that `<p>` tag which has a preceding sibling of `div` that has an ID of `intsect`:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
@$doc->loadHTMLFile("stathtml/" . $file);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$p = $xpath->query('//p[preceding-sibling::div[@id="intsect"]]');
if($p->length > 0) {
    echo $p->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/gtZ6pX)

Comment: While that works to an extent, how would I allow it to accept multiple `<p></p>` tags. I tweaked it to this: `$p = $xpath->query('//p[preceding-sibling::div[@id="intsect"] and following::blockquote]');` since blockquote follows all `<p>` tags. It doesn't collect all the `<p>` tags though.

Comment: @Mitch if you already got a `DOMNodeList` from the query then just iterate on those, i just used `->item(0)` since i just based my answer on your example above. on the answer above it just gets a single one

Comment: It worked. I used a for loop and put `echo $p->item($i)->nodeValue . "<br>";` inside it. Thanks for the help.